# why the following code prints 100? 

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

I have the following structs

```
struct A 
{
   int i;
   A() { i = 0; }
   A(int _i) : i(_i) {}
   virtual void f() { cout << i; }
};



struct B1 : virtual A {
   B1() : A(1) { f(); }
   void f() { cout << i+10; }
};


struct B2 : virtual A {
   B2(int i) : A(2) { f(); }
};


struct C : B1, B2 {
   C() : B2(3) {}
};
```

please explain why the following code prints 100: (10+0)

```
 C* c = new C();
```

I think it should print 1111:
first A() : i = 0
then B1() : i = 1 and prints `B1::f()` - 11
then B2() : prints prints `B1::f()` - 11

Where I go wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Adding some newlines to your print statements would help clarify the issue.

Comment: -1 It's always worth doing a quick [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%2B%2B+are+struct+members+public+or+private) first. The [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_classes#Differences_between_struct_and_classes_in_C.2B.2B) answers this one quite easily.

Comment: -1, Bad descrption, does it print `10` or `100` now? Be more accurate and care more about how you ask your questions.

Comment: I have changed the question, please try to answer it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the inheritance, the C object "contains" a B1 object and a B2 object. Both the B1 and the B2 object "contain" an A object, but since you have virtual inheritance of A, you only have one A object in each C object, not two. This single A object is initialized using A's default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Public by default in a struct.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't print `100`, it prints `10` followed by `0`.

> Struct means that the fields are private by default or public?

Public.

Comment: I know for sure that it prints 10 and then 0 (this is the answer, but I can't understand why)
Can you explain why?